# Automation via python

Tags: python-3.x

Completely new to python so forgive me if this a dumb question.
Part of my working tasks is to upgrade the IOS on various Cisco routers and switches.
The most mind numbing part of this is comparing the pre change config with the post change config.
I use ExamDiff for this but with up to 100 devices each night this gets soul destroying.
Is it possible to get python to open ExamDiff and automatically compare the pre and post checks, saving the differences to a file for each device?
I know I can use the import os command to open ExamDiff but I have no idea how to get ExamDiff to work

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use ExamDiff? Python's built in [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) might be a better choice for this.

Comment: The problem with difflib is that the file lines aren't in sync. Line 13 on 1 file might be line 15 onthe second file. ExamDiff recognises this and matches the lines

Comment: Maybe [meld](https://meldmerge.org/)?

Comment: Maybe bash is better suited for this. E.g. vs code can be launched to diff from command line (`code -diff file1 file2`). With bash you could easily write a script that would open vscode for all diffs you need to do. Or, if you prefer, write a python script that starts [subprocesses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for you for each diff you have to make

Answer (score 0):

I got this..........
Works pretty well

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

path  = input("Enter the files location: ")

def nexus():
    rootdir = path + os.sep 
    filelist = os.listdir(rootdir)
    if filelist:
        for file in filelist:
            if 'pre' in file:
                prefile = file
                postfile = file.replace('pre', 'post')
                resultfile = file.replace('pre', 'report')
                if postfile in filelist:
                    prefile = rootdir + prefile
                    postfile = rootdir + postfile
                    resultfile = rootdir + resultfile
                    compare(prefile, postfile, resultfile)
                else:
                    print('No corresponding "post"-file to {0}.'.format(prefile))
    else:
        print('No files found.')


def compare(file1loc, file2loc, comparefileloc):

    with open(file1loc, 'r') as file1:
        file1lines = file1.readlines()
        file1lines = [x.strip() for x in file1lines]  # getting rid of whitespace and breaks
    with open(file2loc, 'r') as file2:
        file2lines = file2.readlines()
        file2lines = [x.strip() for x in file2lines]  # getting rid of whitespace and breaks

    with open(comparefileloc, 'w') as comparefile:
        comparefile.write('===== IN FILE 1 BUT NOT FILE 2 =====\r\n')
        for file1line in file1lines:
            if not file1line in file2lines:
                comparefile.write(file1line + '\r\n')
        comparefile.write('\r\n')
        comparefile.write('===== IN FILE 2 BUT NOT FILE 1 =====\r\n')
        for file2line in file2lines:
            if not file2line in file1lines:
                comparefile.write(file2line + '\r\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nexus()
```

Comment: This produces an output with a list of things in file 1 that aren't in file 2 and vice versa.
How would I go about getting the 2 lists to sit side by side rather than the list of things in file 2 that aren't in file 1 sitting underneath the list of things in file 1 that aren't in file 2?